# Blocked out of second hand iPhone

Tags: iphone, restore

My phone was bought second hand, restored to factory settings already, from a second hand shop. I can't get in to it because someone's "Find my iPhone" is still on it. I do not know this person and the store won't help.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

If it is bought second hand it would not be marked as lost/stolen in iCloud, so you can reach out for online services as iphoneimei.net and get the activation lock removed.